# Algorithm to generate a point grid out of a plane equation

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, geometry

I have a plane equation in 3D-space: *ax* + *by* + *cz* + *d* = 0 and I want to fill this plane within a given radius from a specific point on the plane with regulary distributed points. It seems to me, that there *should* be a mathematical elegant answer, but I fail to see it. Answer in C++ or pseudo-code will be better.

Comment: Please provide an example, what you have tried already, and where you specifically had problems. This is not a "give me code for my specification" website

Comment: A given radius from what? a specific point on the plane? without that information the question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Save: Right. A given radius from a specific point on the plane.

Comment: Hint: pick two orthogonal vectors in your plane.  You can now use these as a transformation matrix that takes points from the x-y plane into your plane.

Comment: @nyarlathotep: I don't have any idea how to do it... The only solution I see now is to pick two extreme points on the plane, iterate between and cut the one out of the radius...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll assume you have a reasonably good 3d vector class, and call it vec3 in the answer. The first thing you need is a vector in your plane. There are a few ways to generate one given the normal-plane equation, but I prefer this one:

```
vec3 getPerpendicular(vec3 n)
{
  // find smallest component
  int min=0;
  for (int i=1; i<3; ++i)
    if (abs(n[min])>abs(n[i]))
      min=i;

  // get the other two indices
  int a=(min+1)%3;
  int b=(min+2)%3;

  vec3 result;
  result[min]=0.f;
  result[a]=n[b];
  result[b]=-n[a];
  return result;
}
```

This construction guarantees that dot(n, getPerpendicular(n)) is zero, which is the orthogonality condition, while also keeping the magnitude of the vector as high as possible. Note that setting the component with the smallest magnitude to 0 also guarantees that you don't get a 0,0,0 vector as a result, unless that is already your input. And in the case, your plane would be degenerate.

Now to get your base vectors in the plane:

```
vec3 n(a,b,c); // a,b,c from your equation
vec3 u=normalize(getPerpendicular(n));
vec3 v=cross(u, n);
```

Now you can generate your points by scaling u and v and adding it to the vector you got on the plane.

```
float delta = radius/N; // N is how many points you want max in one direction
float epsilon=delta*0.5f;

for (float y=-radius; y<radius+epsilon; radius+=delta)
   for (float x=-radius; x<radius+epsilon; radius+=delta)
      if (x*x+y*y < radius*radius) // only in the circle
          addPoint(P+x*u+y*v); // P is the point on the plane
```

The epsilon makes sure your point count is symmetric and you don't miss the last point on the extremes.

Comment: Could you explain more `getPerpendicular()`? I don't get what you're doing there... (I even think there is something wrong at the end...)

Comment: The condition for orthogonal vectors is that dot(a,b)==0. You can always construct such a vector by setting one component to zero, swapping the other two and reversing the sign of one of them. This is so that, in the dot product equation, one product is zero and the other two cancel each other out. Note that one of the two components you swap should be non-zero, or your result will be 0,0,0 (which is technically perpendicular to everything, but useless here)

Comment: For example, if you have a vector x,y,z - the vector 0,z,-y is always perpendicular, because 0*x+y*z-y*z is always 0.

Comment: So shouldn't it be `result[a] = n[b]; result[b] = -n[a];` either?

Comment: Yea, I messed that up, sorry - will fix

Comment: Your `getPerpendicular` code uses `i` rather than `min` after calculating `min`.  Should be using `min`

Comment: You're right, I fixed it.